# user-friendly message for WCF exception

Tags: wcf

so far, i just tell user that an error happens, please retry. what message should be more user-friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best message would be no message. That is, if your code can automatically handle the error for the user by re-trying a set number of times, or perhaps scheduling the work for later.

Failing that, a message specific to the user's task would be most useful. For example, instead of "An error occurred" you might say "Your order could not be submitted right now - please try again later" or something to that effect.